# Using into() inside a monad pipeline

Tags: types, rust, monads

I'm basically trying to convert a value inside a pipeline like so:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum MyType { A, B }

impl Into<MyType> for i32 {
    fn into(self) -> MyType {
        match self {
            0 => MyType::A,
            _ => MyType::B
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Result<i32, ()> = Ok(0);
    a.map(|int| int.into())
        .and_then(|enm| if enm == MyType::A { println!("A"); });
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that `map()` doesn't know which type it should be outputting.

Other things I've tried which didn't work:

```
a.map(|int| if int.into() as MyType == MyType::A { println!("A"); });

a.map(|int| int.into::<MyType>())
        .and_then(|enm| if enm == MyType::A { println!("A"); });
```

This does work, but feels unnecessarily complex:

```
a.map(|int| {
    let enm: MyType = int.into();
    if enm == MyType::A { println!("A"); }
});
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your original code doesn't work because `and_then` expects a `Result`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not be implementing `Into`, you should be implementing `From`, which automatically gives you an `Into` impl. Then you can call `a.map(MyType::from)` and everything works:

```
impl From<i32> for MyType {
    fn from(i: i32) -> MyType {
        match i {
            0 => MyType::A,
            _ => MyType::B
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Result<i32, ()> = Ok(0);
    a.map(MyType::from)
        .and_then(|enm| if enm == MyType::A { Err(()) } else { Ok(enm) } );
}
```

alternatively you can call `a.map(Into::<MyType>::into)`, but that's rather verbose. There's a reason for the `From`/`Into` duality, it's explained in the [`std::convert` module docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

> The problem I'm running into is that `map()` doesn't know which type it should be outputting.

That's not the problem.

The error is:

```
<anon>:16:25: 16:63 error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::result::Result<_, ()>`,
    found `()`
(expected enum `core::result::Result`,
    found ()) [E0308]
<anon>:16         .and_then(|enm| if enm == MyType::A { println!("A"); });
```

That's because `Result::and_then`'s type is

```
fn and_then<U, F: FnOnce(T) -> Result<U, E>>(self, op: F) -> Result<U, E>
```

So it expects the function to return a `Result<U, E>`. It's meant to be used to chain functions that return a `Result` and to return the first encountered error, if it encounters any.

If you just want to execute some code if you have an `Ok(_)`, you should use `if let` or `match`:

```
fn main() {
    let a: Result<i32, ()> = Ok(0);
    if let Ok(MyType::A) = a.map(|int| int.into()) {
        println!("A");
    }
}
```

prints

```
A
```